# dhcp/named client identification issue

Tags: dhcp, isc-dhcpd

I am running CentoS 7.6 which has been configured as DNS server (via named) and a DHCP server.

In DHCP I have configured dynamic updates to my DNS zone such that new client leases will result in automatic updates in named.

The problem is that certain clients (particularily Android phones) identify themselves (via their client identifier) as androidxxx (some long string) which isn't a particularily helpful DNS entry. It makes it difficult to distinguish whose phone is connecting.

This is only a small network (approx 50 devices) and I want to know if I can make a server side change to better identify who has connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your DHCP server is the one performing the dynamic DNS updates, simply tell it the name you wish the phone to be registered as:

```
host androidphone {
    hardware ethernet 11:22:33:44:55:66;
    ddns-hostname "android";
    option host-name "android";
}
```

The `ddns-hostname` option tells the DHCP server the name to register into DNS, while the `option host-name` makes the DHCP server tell the Android phone the name it's supposed to identify itself as. Ideally these two should be the same.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you!